# Internal Server Error when creating Conditional Access Policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I referred to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conditionalaccessroot-post-policies?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to make a POST request.

Below is the error while making a POST request to create a conditional access policy

```js
{
  "message": "There was an internal server error while processing the request. Error ID: 2dbb1530-4ce6-44f5-9c63-08de28d7218a",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "2dbb1530-4ce6-44f5-9c63-08de28d7218a"
  }
}
```

Payload being passed with the request is below:

```js
{
  "displayName": "Test Policy",
  "state": "enabled",
  "conditions": {
    "clientAppTypes": ["modern", "browser"],
    "applications": {
      "includeApplications": ["None"]
    },
    "users": {
      "includeUsers": [
        "08290005-23ba-46b4-a377-b381d651a2fb"
      ]
    },
    "locations": {
      "includeLocations": ["All"],
      "excludeLocations": ["AllTrusted"]
    }
  },
  "grantControls": {
    "operator": "OR",
    "builtInControls": ["approvedApplication"]
  }
}
```

I've tried using this endpoint to get a policy:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{tenant_id}/conditionalAccess/policies
```

Which successfully returns an existing policy. However, the above POST request is not working.

Comment: Could you try `"includeApplications": "none"` or `"includeApplications": []`? I suspect the capitalization might matter here.

Answer (score 1):

The "approvedApplication" requirement only supports the iOS and Android for device platform condition. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/technical-reference#approved-client-app-requirement).

You need to add "includePlatforms" `iOS` and `android` into the json body.

```
{
  "displayName": "Test Policy",
  "state": "enabled",
  "conditions": {
    "clientAppTypes": ["modern", "browser"],
    "applications": {
      "includeApplications": ["None"]
    },
    "users": {
      "includeUsers": [
        "08290005-23ba-46b4-a377-b381d651a2fb"
      ]
    },
    "platforms": {
        "includePlatforms": [
            "iOS", "android"
        ]
    },  
    "locations": {
      "includeLocations": ["All"],
      "excludeLocations": ["AllTrusted"]
    }
  },
  "grantControls": {
    "operator": "OR",
    "builtInControls": ["approvedApplication"]
  }
}
```

Comment: @Prashant. I agree. But if you want to set "approvedApplication" in "builtInControls", you have to specific `iOS` or `android` platforms. You can do the same thing on Azure Portal to verify it. If you don't select the `iOS` or `android` platforms, it will give an error "MAM policy should be applied to Android or IOS client platforms."

Comment: @AllenWu Appreciate your quick response. I tried with the same input as pasted by you but getting the same error.

 {"message": "There was an internal server error while processing the request. Error ID: e5c40725-97c4-473a-82b6-8584e7c9ce8c",  "innerError": {     "request-id": "e5c40725-97c4-473a-82b6-8584e7c9ce8c }

Comment: @Gursimran, where did you test the call? Have you tried it in Microsoft Graph  Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer? The error message you provided is not enough for me to troubleshoot the issue. Please add more details after you test it in Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Comment: @AllenWu Someone has tried it on Graph Explorer and it seems to be working fine. Please refer this separate thread https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6390 on same issue. However, When I tried with the same payload I am getting the same error.